# Programmatically getting selected text font name in TextEdit

Tags: macos, macos-carbon, textedit

Is it possible to retrieve font name of selected text in TextEdit (by ObjC or Carbon)?
I tryed this code but the "value" is null:

```
AXUIElementRef systemWideElement = AXUIElementCreateSystemWide();
AXUIElementRef focussedElement = NULL;
AXError error = AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(systemWideElement,
    kAXFocusedUIElementAttribute, (CFTypeRef*)&focussedElement);
CFTypeRef value;
AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(focussedElement, kAXFontTextAttribute, &value);
```

Thanks.

Comment: What's the value of `focussedElement` after `AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue` returns?

Comment: The value of focussedElement after AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue returns is valid (not null).

Answer (score 2):

Note that `kAXFontTextAttribute` is declared in AXTextAttributedString.h. It isn't an attribute of UI elements; it's an attribute of text in an attributed string.

Try the `kAXAttributedStringForRangeParameterizedAttribute` instead, passing the value you got for `kAXSelectedTextRangeAttribute`. (That's assuming that the focused UI element is an AXTextArea. You shouldn't assume that.) That will return an AXTextAttributedString from which you can get a font dictionary by the `kAXFontTextAttribute` attribute.

Comment: Thankyou, It works, but I dont know how to retrieve font name from returned value. can you help me?

Comment: @mhtaqia: From the attributed string or the font dictionary?

Comment: I tryed this: CFAttributedStringRef attr_str; AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(focussedElement, kAXAttributedStringForRangeParameterizedAttribute, (CFTypeRef*)&attr_str); the attr_str is returned (not null) and I try to get length by CFAttributedStringGetLength(attr_str), but an error occured, also tryed CFDictionaryRef dic = CFAttributedStringGetAttributes(attr_str, 0, NULL) and error occured, It seems the attr_str is not an AttributedString type? do I use a wrong method?

Comment: @mhtaqia: Since it's a parameterized attribute, you need to use a different function to get the attributed string: `AXUIElementCopyParameterizedAttributeValue`.

Comment: I tryed the [UIBrowser](http://pfiddlesoft.com/uibrowser/), this program shows that the AttributedString is empty; It seems TextEdit do not implement AttributedString. However thankyou Peter.

Comment: @mhtaqia: TextEdit uses NSTextView, which should support it—I'd be surprised if it doesn't. Make sure that you're passing a range that's within the text and covers at least one character—an empty range (length zero) will yield an empty string.

Comment: Hey, i know this is late but @PeterHosey, everything you said work. I was able to get a nsattributedstring from selected range and even transform it to html.